# Given a set of random points that are randomly linked, how to position them so that their link lines do not intersect?

Tags: c#, wpf, math, line, intersection

I have a set of points, the coordinates are not predetermined and I can set them when I create them, but their links are predetermined.  A point can have one or more links, but not zero.

I want to be able to generate a visual representation of these points at positions where these link lines between them will not intersect.  From what I've learned in researching so far, I believe this will be somewhat similar to a planar graph, however there will be points with only one link, and I'm not sure planar graphs are able to represent these.

I'm not sure if there is a good way of doing what I am trying to do or not, but I'll admit that maths is not my strong suite.  My 'best' idea so far is to somehow detect these intersections and then move points in a direction that somehow takes the intersection location into account to reposition them so that that particular intersection does not occur....and to loop and do this for every point until no more intersections are detected.  However there could well be some sort of more efficient mathematical algorithm that I could use instead that I am simply unaware of.

I'm interested in all advice here, whether it is efficient or not.

Comment: Sounds like an [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problem... Which means it'll be very hard to do efficiently.

Comment: What if the points form a non-planar graph, like a pentagram? There's no way to remove all of the intersections in that case.

Comment: For your pentagram example, which points would be connected to which (it's technically just two unconnected overlapping triangles).  I do not understand how it would not be possible to remove all the intersections in your example as it currently stands because you'd simply need to move the points for one of the triangles.

Comment: It depends on the number of points, edges, and faces (area bound by edges) including +1 for the "face" which is the surrounding space around the graph.  This has been taken from wikipedia "Euler's formula states that if a finite, connected, planar graph is drawn in the plane without any edge intersections, and v is the number of vertices, e is the number of edges and f is the number of faces (regions bounded by edges, including the outer, infinitely large region), then
v − e + f = 2."   So basically if your edges and vertices don't fit the criteria to make this happen, you can't make it planar

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy problem. Here are the [Google search results for “algorithm to draw a planar graph”](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=algorithm+to+draw+a+planar+graph&oq=algorithm+to+draw+a+planar+graph&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30.1213.4760.0.4995.32.15.0.13.13.2.371.1971.5j9j0j1.15.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.S8C3Jt7kPUE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48293060,d.dmQ&fp=ac6f38f6fb8d0d50&biw=1075&bih=742). The Boost C++ Library has [some support for drawing planar embeddings](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_graphs.html) including [an example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/example/straight_line_drawing.cpp). These of course use C++, not the C# you tagged the problem with.